# jQuery: shorten code

Tags: jquery

Can this code be shorten in some way? I've tried several ways to compact it, but I can't get it to work:

```
    //Customer info
$('input#state-field-a, input#state-field-b').hide();
$('select#country-a').change(function(){      
  if ($(this).val() === "United States" || $(this).val() === "Canada" ||$(this).val() === "null")
  {
    $('select#state-a').show();
    $('input#state-field-a, input#state-field-b').hide();
     } else {
    $('select#state-a').hide();
    $('input#state-field-a').show();
  } 
});
//Shipping nfo
$('select#country-b').change(function(){      
  if ($(this).val() === "United States" || $(this).val() === "Canada" ||$(this).val() === "null")
  {
    $('select#state-b').show();
    $('input#state-field-b').hide();
     } else {
    $('select#state-b').hide();
    $('input#state-field-b').show();
  } 
});
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to give some context to this.

I have two areas in the same page, one for Billing/Customer Info and other for Shipping Info, when the user selects an option from the select menu, other options show/hide within the same section. Both functions should work 'independent' than each other since they belong to different sections.

For example, if I select *Canada* from the Customer Info select menu, it can't change/alter anything in the Shipping Info section.

Not sure if that makes sense.

Thanks again for any help on this.

Comment: I think your section select.change is supposed to be `select#country-b`?

Comment: Yeah these are currently the same thing.

Comment: am i missing something or do you have the EXACT same select change code twice ??

Comment: It makes it hard to answer when you keep changing the code...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just updated the code and added some context to the code.

Comment: @Ricardo - I think you could do away with so many specific ID's, but could you shed more light on how both these sections behave differently apart from the fact that one is for Billing and the other for Shipping? Also, a screenshot showing both sections and the fields they contain may help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a few shortcut functions to narrow all of your code down to this:

```
$('#state-field-a, #state-field-b').hide();
$('#country-a, #country-b').change(function(){
  var m = $.inArray($(this).val(), ["United States","Canada","null"]) != -1;

  $('#' + this.id.replace('country', 'state') + '-a').toggle(m);
  if(this.id === 'country-a') $('#state-field-b').toggle(m);

  $('#' + this.id.replace('country', 'state-field') + '-a').toggle(!m);
});
```

We're doing a few things different here:

- Not using tag selectors on IDs
- Using [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) once, since they both have the same effect
- Using [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to narrow down the `if` or clauses (IE doesn't have `.indexOf()`...)
- Use [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of repeated [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) code
- The extra `if` is to account for the difference in your two handlers

Comment: @bschaeffer - I'm not using `.toggle()`, I'm using `.toggle(bool)`, which is `.toggle(showIfImTrueHideOtherwise)` :) It's equivalent to `$(selector)[bool ? "show" : "hide"]();`

Comment: I deleted my comment because I didn't realize `.toggle(bool)` was an option... commented too quickly. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Anywhere you select an id, start with the id. Everything before an id selector is irrelevant.

Ex:

```
$('#state-field-a, #state-field-b').hide();
```

Reduce all code duplication. This can be made into a function:

```
    if ($(this).val() === "United States" || $(this).val() === "Canada" ||$(this).val() === "null")
  {
    $('select#state-a').show();
    $('input#state-field-a, input#state-field-b').hide();
     } else {
    $('select#state-a').hide();
    $('input#state-field-a, select#state-b').show();
  }
```

Replace your if statement with this more modular statement:

```
var acceptedCountries = ["United States", "Canada", "null"];
if( $.inArray($(this).val(), acceptedCountries) > 0 )
```

Comment: `$.inArray()` would return `0` if it was `"United States"` :)

Answer (score 1):

First, in your html, change select id's to classes like so:

```
<select id="a" class="country">...</select>
<select id="b" class="country">...</select>
```

Then you can shorten it this way (**edited using `.toggle(bool)` from Nick's answer**):

```
var inputs = $('#state-field-a, #state-field-b'),
    selects = $('select.country'),
    countries = {'United States', 'Canada'};

inputs.hide();

selects.change(function() { 
    var value = $(this).val(),
        toggle = ($.inArray(value, countries) != -1 || value === "null");

    $(this).toggle(toggle);
    inputs.toggle(toggle);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a shortening of your code, and in fact it maybe a little but longer than your code :)

You could do without too many id's and referencing specific elements by making it generic. As far as I can tell, both the billing and shipping sections work exactly alike with maybe a difference or two. If so, you can have an identical structure for both such as:

```
<div id='billing' class='address'>
    <select class='country'> .. </select>
    <select class='state'> .. </select>
    <input type='text' class='state-field'>
</div>

<div id='shipping' class='address'>
    <select class='country'> .. </select>
    <select class='state'> .. </select>
    <input type='text' class='state-field'>
</div>
```

By grouping each under a parent and only using the id for - `#billing`, `#shipping`, everything underneath can follow exactly the same structure. Here is the callback handler for when a country is changed (thanks for @Nick Craver for the toggle trick):

```
function countryChanged() {
    var countries = $(this);
    var selectedCountry = countries.val();
    var container = $(this).closest('.address');

    var shouldShowStates = function(country) {
        return ['United States', 'Canada', 'null'].indexOf(country) != -1;
    }

    var toggleFields = function(showList) {
        $('.state', container).toggle(showList);
        $('.state-field', container).toggle(!showList);
    }

    var showStates = shouldShowStates(selectedCountry);
    toggleFields(showStates);
}


$('.country').change(countryChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/nK2T3/

You need to use a selector context variable to limit the scope of your selection to the appropriate section. For the sake of argument, I assumed your inputs were segregated into fieldsets:

```
var countrySelects = '#country-a, #country-b',
    stateSelects = '#state-a, #state-b',
    stateInputs = '#state-field-a, #state-field-b';    

$(stateInputs).hide();

$('fieldset').each(function () {
    var $fieldset = $(this);

    $(countrySelects, $fieldset).change(function () {
        var $countrySelect = $(this),
            $stateSelect = $(stateSelects, $fieldset),
            $stateInput = $(stateInputs, $fieldset);

        if ($countrySelect.val() === "United States" || $countrySelect.val() === "Canada" || $countrySelect.val() === "null") {
            $stateSelect.show();
            $stateInput.hide();
        } else {
            $stateSelect.hide();
            $stateInput.show();
        }
    })
});​
```